# Opening an external link from a localhost reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting data from an API. One of the values from the API and stored in an object is a URL. I've displayed the URL but clicking the link doesn't do anything when it should open in a new tab normally. Is there something I am not doing right?
Here's my code snippet:

```
render(){
 let items = this.state.items
      return (
        <div>
          {items.map(item => 
          <h4 key={item.url}>
            <a href='{item.url}'>{item.title}</a>
          </h4>)}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: <a href={item.url}>

Comment: remove `''` use this:  `<a href={item.url}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put quotes to reflect JSX value:

```
<a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
```

Comment: How silly of me. I just realized same and just came to say so. Thanks.